# How to do a clean uninstall/install of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Operating System: Windows 10

Background of the issue: I was working on an C# web MVC type of project on VS2015, my computer suddenly crashed (due to memory issue.) Then, I restarted VS2015, and tried to load my project; however, the solution explorer would not show my files, so I decided to try different projects and the same issue happened. Therefore, I decided to create a new project, but the new project window would not display the templates at all (F#, C#, web MVC ...etc.)

So I figured some VS2015 files got corrupted, so I decided to do the following:

1. Ran repair through the installation
2. uninstalled, then installed VS2015 again.
3. I uninstalled through Revo Uninstaller, deleted all the registries, and folders. Then, I ran regedit and manually deleted all VS2015 registries (I was getting desperate)

None of the above worked...

P.S. I am using the Community edition.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I have already done that, and the issue persists.

Comment: Installers generally don't (and shouldn't) install, repair or uninstall your settings for an application. Try logging in as a different user to narrow the problem down.

Comment: @TomBlodget, wow thank you so much for the advice! I installed it again, and launched VS on a new user in my PC, and it works perfectly. It seems that the problem is only with my main user. That certainly narrowed things down form me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @TomBlodget answered, the issue was with the Windows user where the incident happened. When I launched VS on a new windows user, it worked fine. For now, I will keep using the new Windows user and once I figure out what happened with the original user, I will post it here for future reference.

Comment: Just in case if anyone still facing the same issue. I was able to fix it on the main user by downloading the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Mount the iso, if it's drive letter is 'd', run the code below in command prompt. (replace 'd' with the drive letter)

D:\vs_community.exe /uninstall /force